# Iterate through list and replace instance in a certain index?

Tags: python

I have a list called `List` for the purpose of this question, which contains tuples.

```
List = [
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 0),
    ("foo", "bar", 3, 1),
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 2)
]
```

In index position `2` (third item in list) of each sub-list, I need to replace with the corresponding item in another list.

```
References = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]
```

The expected output would be the new `List` of:

```
List = [
    ("foo", "bar", "one", 0),
    ("foo", "bar", "three", 1),
    ("foo", "bar", "one", 2)
]
```

Notice how there are also integers on other parts of the list but these remain unchanged.

My current code replaces **all** instances of integers which is *not* what I want:

```
for r in range(0, len(References)):
    for i in List:
        List[List.index(i)] = [References[t] if x==t else x for x in i]
```

**Q:** How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I made a mistake with my code - inside `List` are tuples, not lists.

Comment: Are `one`, `three` etc. supposed to be variable names (as they are in your definitions of `List`) or string literals `"one"` etc. (as they are in your definition of `References`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are immutable which means you cannot update or change the values of tuple elements. You can follow any one of the following process:

**1)** You can take portions of existing tuples to create new tuples as the following:

```
List_One = [
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 0),
    ("foo", "bar", 3, 1),
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 2)
]

List_Two = []

References = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]

for i in List_One:
    tup = (i[0], i[1], References[i[2]], i[3])
    List_Two.append(tup)

print(List_Two)
```

**2)** You can convert tuples to lists, change as you desire, change back the lists to tuples.

```
List = [
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 0),
    ("foo", "bar", 3, 1),
    ("foo", "bar", 1, 2)
]

References = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]

for i in range(len(List)):
    List[i] = list(List[i])

for i in List:
    i[2] = References[i[2]]

for i in range(len(List)):
    List[i] = tuple(List[i])

print(List)
```

Comment: Gives `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: @nx_prv I have updated my answer with two different process. You can follow any one.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to do this ?

```
for el in List: el[2] = References[el[2]]
```

Comment: It gives `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Oh, when I looked at your code I thought there was only lists. Well, do you really want to deal with tuples ? Because if not, you can just replace the `()` in `List` by `[]`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below code snippet,

```
List = [
    ["foo", "bar", 1, 0],
    ["foo", "bar", 3, 1],
    ["foo", "bar", 1, 2]
]

References = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]

for each in List:
    if list(each):
        each[2]=References[each[2]]
print(List)
```

Note: Reference list position is consdiered as string equvivalent.

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid capititalization of variable names (stick to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the naming conventions).

Second, you can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [
...     ["foo", "bar", 1, 0],
...     ["foo", "bar", 3, 1],
...     ["foo", "bar", 1, 2]
... ]
>>> references = ["zero", "one", "two", "three"]
>>> [row[:2]+[references[row[2]]]+row[3:] for row in L]
[['foo', 'bar', 'one', 0], ['foo', 'bar', 'three', 1], ['foo', 'bar', 'one', 2]]
```

The original list will not be modified, but a new list will be generated. (Will only work if you have lists, not tuples.)

Third, I guess that `one`, `two`, ... is just an example. If you really want number in plain text, instead of hard-coding the `references` list, you can use some libraries to do the number to word conversion, [num2words](https://pypi.org/project/num2words) for instance.

Four, you are performing the equivalent of a SQL `JOIN`. Current code will fail (raise a `KeyError`) if the reference is unknwon:

- for an `INNER JOIN`, just check if `row[2] in references` and skip the row if that's not the case.
- for a `LEFT JOIN`, replace `references[row[2]]` by `references.get(row[2])` of `references.get(row[2], <default value>)`.